# Testng throwing java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, exception, testng

I am using `testng` as my automation framework. When the line of code below is executed in a test case  it results in a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this? My method should wait for 2 minutes.

```
{
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.wait(2);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc for the `wait()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) says:

> The current thread must own this object's monitor.

In other words, you can only call `Object.wait` on an object within a `synchronized` method or block that is locking the object you are waiting on.

You should probably be using `Thread.sleep(...)` or `TimeUnit.sleep(...)`.  Read the respective javadocs to understand the units of the parameters.

If you do use `wait`, then your usage is incorrect for another reason as well.  Though it *looks* like you are waiting for 2 minutes, you are *actually* waiting for 2 milliseconds ... because you are calling the `Object` implementation of `wait`.  If you wanted to use the `TimeUnit` version, your code would need to look like this:

```
synchronized lock {
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.timedWait(lock, 2);
}
```

where `lock` is a suitable (private, unshared) object we are using for locking.

Also, beware that if anything *notifies* the lock / locked object, then your `wait(...)` call will wake up early.  This makes `wait` and inappropriate solution in most if not all cases where you just want to wait for a given period time.

Comment: If you're going to spend effort on this question, you might as well tell the OP that waiting for 2 minutes is done via `wait(120000)` in a loop, rather than the hideous monstrosity in the post.

Comment: In fact, `Object.wait()` is rarely appropriate at all when you need a thread to pause for a fixed (minimum) amount of time, because the thread invoking `wait()` is explicitly permitted to resume sooner than the specified timeout (even when the object it is waiting on is not `notify()`ed).

Answer (score 0):

With `TimeUnit`s and `Lock`s you have to take care not to invoke accidentally the methods inherited from `java.lang.Object`, i.e. [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)),`notify`, etc., as they have an entirely different semantics.

For what you want to achieve, you have to call [`TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)).